# iOS: In-app purchase on sandbox mode giving us multiple transactions under one receipt

Tags: ios, storekit, xcode7.3, in-app, auto-renewable

We are facing issue with iOS: In-app purchase on sandbox mode giving us multiple transactions under one receipt.

Here's the link for Gist git for Receipt

https://gist.github.com/ApplifyNishant/620ac00e18ca4292065f8e53fdbcd890

It showing me multiple in-app purchased transactions for single purchase. We are using Auto-Renewable.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you end up finding a solution?

Comment: did you get the solution to this?